# Magento Custom Payment Plugin : How to add a Hook on PLACE ORDER?

Tags: magento, payment, checkout

I'm trying to make a custom payment plugin for Magento.
My new Payment method is showing in Payment Information on Checkout page.

Now what I want is that when Place Order is pressed, I want to trigger a JS code ...

Any ideas about it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whats so difficult about that?

Add your JS code to the last step in the checkout:

```
/template/checkout/onepage/review.phtml
```

Comment: If I'm not wrong are you suggesting changing the Magento's core checkout template file ?? But if this is a 3rd party plugin how can I modify a core file ?

Comment: Yes thats right. Just create a layout file, override the template path for the review.phtml to yours and thats it. Just google for some tutorials on "Magento overriding a template file". Im wondering how you could manage to create a new payment module but not knowing how to override template files